# Pass multiple values for cellRendererFramework using ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have only seen one SO question relating to this and there were no answers posted.

I have an angular app usnig ag-grid. It uses **cellRendererFramework** to render data for a column a to display in the table. I need to have data from the **Date** column to properly format the **Data** column, but cannot find any way to get that into the renderer component. Here's the basic code:

```
  // Columns defined inside the main component
  this.columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Date', field: 'timestamp'},
    { headerName: 'Data',
      field: 'type',
      cellRendererFramework: MyRendererComponent,
    },
  }


  // Inside the renderer component
  export class MyRendererComponent implements OnInit {
    myData: any;

    agInit(params: import("ag-grid-community").ICellRendererParams): void {

      // This is where I need data from the first column to 
      // properly set the return value
      this.myData = this.setUpData(params.value)
    }

  setUpData(data: any) {
    // Operate on the data here, but I need the timestamp to do it properly
  }
  ...
  }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can get the **timestamp** data into **MyRendererComponent**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. Use the data parameter of params to access the row data and get to your field on that data:

```
params.data.timestamp
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderers-and-row-groups

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `CellRendererParams`

```
colDef.cellRenderer = myCellRenderer;
colDef.cellRendererParams = {
    color: 'guinnessBlack'
}
```

Then you can access color using `params.color` in `myCellRenderer`

You can read more about it [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ghanima but I had already found it by using the data field of the params object as indicated in my answer response. I just couldn't accept as an answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

you should send the data with  cellRendererParams example:

```
{
            cellRendererFramework: 'CityCellRenderer',
            cellRendererParams: {currentApartament: this.apartament},
            
          },
```

and you can get the data so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn text icon @click="btnClickedHandler()">
      <v-icon>mdi-delete-outline</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CityCellRenderer',
    methods: {
      btnClickedHandler() {
        console.log(this.params) //please you check the properties.
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but want to send data from the row itself ex:
`cellRendererParams: { label: currentRowData.myField + currentRowData.myOtherField  }`
Not sure how to access row data from within the cellRendererParams.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow you can review this console.log(this.params) //please you check the properties. in there are your values

Comment: I actually posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097384/ag-grid-set-cellrendererparams-to-values-from-the-row-data) question where I got an answer that I was able to use to find a solution.