# ag-grid set cellRendererParams to values from the row data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, cellrenderer

I want to send data to my cellRenderer component via the cellRendererParams object but I don't know how to access row data for this.  Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
cellRendererParams: {
    label: currentRowData.myField + currentRowData.myOtherField
}
```

I don't want my cellRenderer component to have knowledge of the data structure of the grid since I may use it in other grids with different row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways:

1)

```
valueGetter: (params) => ({ property1: params.data.myField1 + params.data.myField2, property2: params.data.someOtherField }),
```

2. 

```
valueFormatter: ({ property1: params.data.myField1 + params.data.myField2, property2: params.data.someOtherField }),
```

Comment: Yes, I used #1 because that comes through the params object's value property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [valueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/), like this:

```js
valueGetter: (params) => params.data.myField + params.data.myOtherField
```

Comment: I guess my example was a little simplistic in that it only shows one item in the cellRendererParams object.  Your suggestion only works for the `value` property of the params object that's passed to the cellRenderer component.  If there are multiple items that I want passed, e.g. `{ label: 'something', someBoolean: data.myBooleanField , someValue: dataRow.oneValue * dataRow.otherValue }`, then your solution doesn't work although, I do appreciate your solution as it does accomplish the simple case.

Comment: So, I took your solution one step further and I was able to make it work.  Instead of the `valueGetter` only returning one value I made it return an object, e.g.  `valueGetter: (params) => ({ property1: params.data.myField1 + params.data.myField2, property2: params.data.someOtherField })`.  If you update your answer to this, I will mark it as the accepted answer.